# How to Join four tables together single query mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have joined 4 tables but on the main table where i stored all data and fids only have 2 records but when i join all table it shows 30+ rows

```
beneficery --- Main table where all final data

pkbenefid | countryid | payout_method | payout_partner
 1             1           2              2
 14            9           4              6
```

```
country--- table

pkcountryid | country_name 
 1             UK          
 3             USA
 9             PK
```

```
Payout_method--- table

pkmethdid | method_name | method_id 
 1             UKCASH        1 
 2             USCASH        3
 3             PKCASH        9
```

```
Payout_partner--- table

pkpartnerid | partner_name | partner_id 
 1             LondonCASH         1 
 2             USAPoint           2
 3             PKJAZZ             3
```

Here is my data base structure i have only 2 records on **Beneficery** table but when i used to fetch all record from the **Beneficery** table it will returent multiple records , please check where is the issue ?

```
<?php
$getbene = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM beneficery b, country c, payout_methods m, payout_partners p WHERE pkbenefid = '$id' AND c.pkcountryid = b.countryid OR m.pkpayoutmethodid = b.payout_methods");
        
        if(mysqli_num_rows($getbene) > 0)
        {
            $x = 1;
            while ($bene = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getbene)){

                $id              = $bene['pkbenefid'];
                $countryid       = $bene['country_name'];
                $payout_methods  = $bene['method_name'];
                $payout_partners = $bene['patner_name'];
                ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $x; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $countryid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $payout_methods; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $payout_partners; ?></td>
        
        <?php
            $x++;
        }
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
```

this will return 15+ records when i getting on the page ? But i have only 2 record can you please guide how to resolve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining 4 Tables in SQL Server Using Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440556/joining-4-tables-in-sql-server-using-join)

Comment: @RobinSingh While the basic ideas are the same, it would probably be better to link to a MySQL question rather than SQL-Server.

Comment: Joining 4 tables is the same as joining 2 or 3 tables. Just specify all the relationships between the tables. You should also learn to use ANSI JOIN syntax rather than archaic cross products.

Comment: When you join a lot of tables, each matched combination forms separate row. For example, tables 2 and 3 contains 2 rows each matched one row in table 1 - so the output will contain 4 rows (row from 1 + 1st row from 2 + 1st row from 3, row from 1 + 1st row from 2 + 2nd row from 3, row from 1 + 2nd row from 2 + 1st row from 3, row from 1 + 2nd row from 2 + 2nd row from 3). This is "join multiplying".

Comment: *how to resolve this ?* Show some sample data for all tables (2-3 rows per table) and desired output for this data.

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your query are:

1. You use `OR` rather than `AND` in your conditions, so you're getting multiple unrelated matches.
2. You didn't specify all the table relationships.

Use a `JOIN` clause for each table, and specify the relationship with the main `beneficery` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM beneficery AS b
JOIN country AS c ON b.countryid = c.pkcountryid
JOIN Payout_method AS m ON b.payout_method = m.pkmethdid
JOIN Payout_partner AS p ON b.payout_partner = p.pkpartnerid
```